# Facebook review rejection affected development

Tags: facebook

After Facebook reviewers rejected to approve publish permissions for our app the app developers can't use these permissions for development.

Before the review was even submitted developers had been developing the app with these permissions, but after the rejection facebook requests are getting declined.

Do developers have to wait until the app is reviewed?

Comment: Put the app in development mode

Comment: @WizKid I can't it must be accessible for non developer users with old permissions

Comment: Then create a test app and do the development on that one